Horizontal scroll not at the end of the element
There is a #horizontal_scroll element with a height of 150vh. It has a child element that is 2 times wider than the parent element. The horizontal scroll of the element #horizontal_scroll is displayed at the end of the element (if you scroll the page to the bottom). Is it possible to display this scroll not at the end of the element (150vh) but at the end of the screen (100vh)?



#horizontal_scroll {
  background: grey;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 150vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
#horizontal_scroll div {
  width: 100vw;
}
<div id="horizontal_scroll">
<div></div>
</div>




Please clarify the problem. What makes you think the scrollbar should be at 100vh, when the parent container is 150vh high?

@DarkBee Can I somehow make the scrollbar be at 100vh and not 150vh?

Add in another container that is 100vh?

Your question is poorly worded. If you want the scrolling component to be start at 100vh (Not visible until you scroll down), You should be able to use absolute position to set the scroll bar to be 100vh down the viewport height.
Otherwise you can just just have a parent component that is display:flex
flex-direction: column
and then make the first component in that 100vh, and the scroll component you're talking about after that but in the parent


#horizontal_scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100vh;
  background: grey;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 150vh;
  overflow: auto;
}



